# Auto filling --Dropbox

Tags: php

i have two text type forms(id,name) and another form dropbox type(school name)(select option type).

when user enters the id form, the remaining form (name) and the drop box(school name) needs to be filled based on the values in mysql.

filling form text type (name) is not a problem which i am able to do using json and jquery ,but i do not know how to auto select the dropbox.

any tutorials or code snippets suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery and Auto-populat selects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548540/jquery-and-auto-populat-selects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your drop box is in xhtml, you can use the "selected" param.

with jquery, you could write semething like :

```
$("#optiontoSelect").attr("selected","selected");
```

More info [in the jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question. If you wish the focus to move from the input field to the select you would use `.focus()`. I would imagine you want to call focus on successful population of the select.

```
$('#select').focus();
```

or

```
$(this).focus();
```

[jQuery Docs : focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Answer (score 1):

This'll get you started:

```
<?php
$options = Array('red', 'green', 'blue');
$opt_from_db = 'green'; // for example

echo '<select name="fieldName">';
foreach ($options as $opt) {
   $selected = ($opt_from_db == $opt) ? ' selected' : '';
   echo "<option{$selected}>{$opt}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

The key is to write the `selected` attribute (in some form or another) into the programmatically-rendered HTML.